# Why is my UIImageView not appearing on the screen?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rubymotion

I don't think I quite understand how to make an image appear on the screen using RubyMotion. All I'm attempting to do at the moment is to get a map of our campus to display on the screen. Here is the code I have right now for the particular view controller:

```
class MapDisplayController < UIViewController

  def initWithNibName(name, bundle: bundle)
    super
    self
  end

  def viewDidLoad
    self.title = "Campus Map"
    # Initialize an image view with an image of the map from a file.
    @map_view = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(UIImage.imageNamed('campus.jpg'))
    @map_view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2,  self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
    # Set some basic accessibility properties.
    @map_view.accessibilityLabel = "RVH Campus Map"
    @map_view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview @map_view
  end

end
```

The view itself loads OK other than the fact it's missing the picture. Am I misunderstanding how to initialize it? Is my `init` function missing something? Should I be using `viewDidAppear` instead?

Comment: I added 4 spaces before each line of your code.  This is how you tell StackOverflow to format it as code and not as just text.

Comment: I ran your code and it works.  Did you put the image file `campus.jpg` in the `resources` directory?

Comment: Yes, campus.jpg is in the resources folder, I just double checked that.

Comment: Since I used your code above verbatim, and it worked, I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.  How are you allocating and presenting `MapDisplayController`?

Comment: I've got a button in another view that pulls it up, like so:

    def tap_campus
    map_display = MapDisplayController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle: nil)
    # Display the view containing the map on the screen, in a hierarchy. A back button will allow the user to return to the previous view.
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(map_display, animated: true)
    end

Comment: Could you try calling just `init` instead.  `map_display = MapDisplayController.alloc.init`?